# Robotium tests from console on android virtual device are not working

Tags: android, android-studio, robotium

Tests in Android Studio works fine but via command line it's not working.

1.I built project in Android Studio 1.3.1, opened virtual device and cmd

```
2. adb install C:\...\build\outputs\apk\Audioteka-debug.apk

3. adb shell pm list instrumentation //there is instrumentation definded in Android Manifest

4. adb shell am instrument -w pl.k2.droidoaudioteka/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

Result:

```
Test results for InstrumentationTestRunner=
Time: 0.001

OK (0 tests)
```

It turns out that there are no test classes in dex in apk.

My tests are in the same project the structure looks like this:

```
    -src
      |
      +--main
      |   |
      |   +--java
      |   |   |
      |   |   +--pl.k2.droidoaudioteka
      |   |          \--AudiotekaApplication.java
      |   |
      |   \--AndroidManifest.xml
      |
      +--test
          |
          +--java
              |
              +--pl.k2.droidoaudioteka
                        |
                        \--_1_2_0_LaunchAfterAppInstallationTest.java
                        |
                        \--_1_2_1_...
```

I've added to manifest

```
<manifest>
....
  <application>
   ...
    <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
  </application>

  <instrumentation
    android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    android:label="RobotiumTest"
    android:targetPackage="pl.k2.droidoaudioteka" />
</manifest>
```

In gradle I have

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
       minSdkVersion 14
       targetSdkVersion 14
       testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"

    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            androidTest.setRoot('src/test')
        }
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
    ...
    androidTestCompile  'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.3.1'

 }
```

and typical test class looks like this:

```
package pl.k2.droidoaudioteka;

import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;

import com.robotium.solo.Solo;

/**
 * Created by Admin on 2015-05-12.
 */
public class _1_2_0_LaunchAfterAppInstallationTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 {
    private Solo solo;
    private long startTime;
    private static final String LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME = "pl.k2.droidoaudioteka.ui.views.impl.smartphone.WelcomeActivity";

    private static Class<?> launcherActivityClass;
    static{
        try {
            launcherActivityClass = Class.forName(LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public _1_2_0_LaunchAfterAppInstallationTest() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        super(launcherActivityClass);
    }

    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation());
        getActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        solo.finishOpenedActivities();
        super.tearDown();
    }

        public void testRun() {
/*      During first launch after app installation, verify if the screen with flags of countries and slider is presented.
        Flags represent local stores.
*/
        //test code here
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

building with command

```
gradlew.bat clean assembleDebug test
```

did the job